# Datagridview winforms cells doesnt get updated unless focus back on the grid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working with winforms c# datagridview and ran into a bug that I m not sure how to resolve. I have a datagridview in which the datasource is a datatable. The datagridview contains editable text fields and cellvaluechanged event as well as button column which I respond to thru a cellclick event. Currently when I change the value in a cell , hit the enter key to leave the just updated cell and click the button. The cellclick event which acts as the button click runs a task (TPL) in which the continuewith of the tasks updates values in the datagridview and that works because all the values that needed to be changed gets changed. The issue is that when I change a text value and don't hit the enter key and just immediately click the button on the row. the ui doesn't get updated intill I click on the cells to see the new values. I have looked this up and found that if I set the

```
datagridview.Currentcell = datagridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4]
```

to the cells that I want to see the new values to. The new values appear. I don't want run for each cell I was wondering if there is a better way in handling this issue?

This is the code:

```
  private void dgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {       
            //Button on grid
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 17)
            {
                string val1 = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                string val2 = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            Task.Factory.StartNew<Dictionary<string, Response>>(() => GenerateData(val1, val2)).ContinueWith(ant => {
                            int rowId = Convert.ToInt32(this.dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value);
                            SetResponse(rowId, this.DataSet.DataTable, ant.Result);
                             // i have tried the code below and it fixes the issue but don't want to go this route
                            //for (int i = 5; i < 12; i++) dgv.CurrentCell = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i];                                                                
                        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
                }
            }
    }
    private void dgv_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
                if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
                {
                    string val1 = this.dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString().Trim();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val1))
                    {
                        //dgv.BeginEdit(false);
                        this.dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value = DBNull.Value;
                        //dgv.EndEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
                    }
                }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `datagridview.EndEdit(true);` ??

Comment: well where would I put that in the cellvalue change or the cellclcick. I tried both and it doesn't accept Boolean as param. also it doesn't work

Comment: sorry, it would be `datagridview.BeginEdit(true);` to put the current cell in edit mode...and `datagridview.EndEdit();` will "commit and end the edit operation.". And I am unclear where to put that code because you haven't provided any events or anything you've tried.

Comment: @AussieJoe  I have put beginedit and endedit in the cellvaluechanged and in the cellclick as well as beginedit and endedit just to try still hasn't worked

Answer (score 1):

By adding these two lines of code resolved the issue

```
this.dgv.EndEdit();
this.dgv.CurrentCell = null;
```

Comment: Thanks it is the correct way to handle!